# problem of Raspberry pi 3b with MQ2 sensor and MCP3002

Tags: pi-3

I am newbie who is learning how to using the sensor on the raspberry pi 3b module.
Recently i have a project is need to use the MQ2 smoke sensor for detect the smoke.
And i have follow this website 
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/MQ-2-smoke-sensor-circuit-with-raspberry-pi.php tutorial.
But it doesn't work.And the error message on the below.

[image]

```python
import time
import botbook_mcp3002 as mcp #

smokeLevel= 0

def readSmokeLevel():
global smokeLevel
smokeLevel= mcp.readAnalog()

def main():
while True: #
readSmokeLevel() #
print ("Current smoke level is %i " % smokeLevel) #
if smokeLevel > 120:
print("Smoke detected")
time.sleep(0.5) # s

if_name_=="_main_":
main()
```

0
down vote
accept

Thank you for joan the answer.Its work.

After that, i test the mq2 sensor by using on fire paper. But it always print "Current smoke level is 0"

Is it the code or other problem? Does anyone have same problem..??

Comment: What is the result of the command `ls /dev/spi*`?

Comment: ls: cannot access /dev/spi* : No such file or directory, does it mean i miss some step on spi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable SPI.

The simplest way is to use `sudo raspi-config` and look under Advanced Options.  You will probably need to reboot for the change to take effect.

Alternatively add the line `dtparam=spi=on` to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.